# htaccess different behaviour with trailing slash on the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules in .htaccess file placed at the root folder

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?$ /testsite/index.php?rel=m
RewriteRule ^about/?$ /testsite/aboutus.php?rel=b
RewriteRule ^ict/?$ /testsite/ict.php?rel=b
RewriteRule ^eeap/?$ /testsite/eeap.php?rel=b
```

The rule for index works fine with or without a trailing slash. However when I hit **http://mydomain.com/testsite/about/** the page is served without CSS and images and works fine if the last slash is removed. This happens with the rule for **ict** too.

For the next rule (**eeap**) things behave the other way. CSS and images go missing if I end the URL with a slash.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about this from the point of view of the web browser.

If the URL does not end with a slash, "/about" for example, then the web browser assumes that it is looking at a file called "about" in the top-level directory of the web server. So any requests in the page generated by "/about" which have relative paths will cause the web browser to produce a full path based on starting off in the top-level directory. For example, a CSS file path of "css/style.css" will cause the browser to start from the top-level and ask for the file from "/css/style.css".

But if the URL does end with a slash, "/about/" in our example, then the web browser believes that it is looking at a sub-directory called "about". Now that same CSS file path "css/style.css" will cause the web browser to ask for the file from "/about/css/style.css".

One CSS file path will be correct, the other will not. Hence the behaviour you're seeing.

There are a few ways to avoid this. You can tell Apache to permanently redirect all requests to either the URL which ends with a slash, or the URL which does not, so that all visitors will end up looking at the same URL. This makes it possible to know what relative CSS and image paths to use in your web pages.

Or you can modify your web pages so that all file paths for CSS, image, JavaScript, etc, are anchored to the top-level directory. So "css/style.css" would become "/css/style.css" for example (note the forward-slash at the start of the path to tell the browser to start from the top-level directory).

Or you could add a bunch of convoluted mod_rewrite rules to try to catch all possible outcomes for CSS files and the like. I don't favour this approach because it will usually make your ruleset more fragile and complicated.