# Fake directories with .htaccess but doesn't works on two condition

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to some redirection with `mod_rewrite`.

Here's what I expect:

1. if there's something like `/tags/exampletag`, it'll do `view.php?tag=exampletag`
2. if there's nothing, just call `view.php?name=titlegoeshere`.

I tried below code, but it returns only one of them above rules.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ view.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tags/(.*)$ view.php?tag=$1 [L]
#also second one doesn't fires style, js files.
#I suppose because of looking a directory which is not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your first rule matches everything, so every request is rewritten to "view.php". Which means that the second rule never gets a match, and never triggers.

If you make the pattern in your first rule much more stringent then you can avoid it matching everything. For instance:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ view.php?name=$1 [L]
```

This will only match requests which do not contain a forward-slash. So "title" would match, but "tags/title" would not. This will allow a request for "tags/title" to slip past to the second rule, which will match it.

Regarding your problem with CSS and JS files not being found, see [my answer to a user who has the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393798/htaccess-different-behaviour-with-trailing-slash-on-the-url/17426347#17426347). (In short, you need to think about where the web browser thinks the page is based when it is reconstructing full file paths from relative CSS, JS and image paths.)

Comment: Thanks. So is there easy way to trick browser "/" limitation?

Comment: What do you mean specifically?

Comment: I mean is there easy way to hande CSS and JS file issue with using mod_rewrite?